# $I(Y) = \{ p(x,y,z) \in k[x,y,z] \mid p (t,t^2,t^3) = 0, \forall t \in k \}$ is prime

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've been working on the following problem from Hartshorne:
Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{ A }^3 $ be the set $Y = \{(t,t^2 , t^3) \mid t \in k \}$.  Show that $Y$ is an affine variety of dimension $1$.
To start with, I proved that $Y$ is an algebraic set:  define polynomials 
$$ f(x,y,z) = x^2 - y \ , \ g(x,y,z) = x^3 - z \in k[x,y,z] $$
Then it's not bad to check that 
$$ Y = Z(f) \cap Z(g) = Z (\{f,g\})$$
Now I need to show that $Y$ is irreducible.  This is equivalent to showing that the ideal of $Y$, 
$$ I(Y) = \{ p(x,y,z) \in k[x,y,z] \mid p (t,t^2,t^3) = 0, \forall t \in k \}$$
is prime.
I tried a direct approach: suppose that $pq \in I(Y)$ for $p,q \in k[x,y,z]$, and suppose that $q \notin I(Y)$.  Then there exists some $s \in k$ for which $q(s,s^2, s^3) \ne 0$.  I don't believe that it necessarily follows that $p \in I(Y)$.  Even though $k$ is an integral domain, the fact that we have one triple $(s,s^2,s^3)$ at which $q$ does not vanish does not force $p$ to vanish at every triple $(t, t^2, t^3)$, $t \in k$.
The Nullstellensatz tells us that 
\begin{align*}
I(Y) &= I(Z(\{f,g\})) \\
 &= \sqrt{(f,g)} \\
\end{align*}
But I wasn't getting anywhere using this fact either.  I don't know much about non-principal ideals and how they relate with prime ideals.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

My apologies if this is overkill, but I'm really trying to understand:
So when you say that 
$$ k[x,y,z]/ (x^2 - y , x^3 - y) = k[x] $$
 You mean that the two are isomorphic right?
 We define a homomorphism $\varphi: k[x,y,z] \rightarrow k[t]$ which sends $x \mapsto t$, $y \mapsto t^2$, $z \mapsto t^3$.  This is surjective: given $p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + \ldots + a_n t^n$, then $\varphi ( \tilde{p}) = p$ where $\tilde{p} = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n \in k[x,y,z]$.
Observing that
    $$ \mbox{Ker} (\varphi) = \{ h \in k[x,y,z] \mid h(t,t^2 , t^3) = 0 \} = I (Y) $$
    then we have that 
    \begin{align*}
 A(Y) &= k[x,y,z]/I(Y) \\
  &= k[x,y,z]/ \mbox{Ker}(\varphi) \\
  &\cong \mbox{Im}(\varphi)\\ 
  &= k[t]
  \end{align*}
     and so it seems to me that it is $I(Y) = \sqrt{J}$, (as opposed to $J$ itself) which is prime.  Of course this gives us that $Y$ is irreducible.
     The problem goes on to ask for generators of $I(Y)$.
     If we get that $J$ is prime immediately, then (since primes are radical) $I(Y) = J$ (as you mention).  If we get that $I(Y)$ is prime, then we don't immediately get that $I(Y) = J$, and we have something left to prove.

Comment: I think it would be easier to consider the homomorphism $k[x, y, z] \to k[t]$ such that $x \mapsto t$, $y \mapsto t^2$, $z \mapsto t^3$. If you show that its kernel is your ideal, you're done.

Comment: a) Yes, I mean canonical isomorphism. b) Yes, *a priori* we get $ I(Y)=\sqrt J$ but since $J$ is prime $\sqrt J=J$ c) I don't use $ ker(\phi)$ and won't comment on that .  If something is still not clear in my answer, feel free to ask but do mention the **exact** location in my answer  that causes a problem. And please ask in a comment under my answer, not under your question.

Answer (score 3):

If $J=(f,g)$, we have $k[x,y,z]/J=k[x,y,z]/(x^2 - y , x^3 - z) =k[x]$, hence $J$ is prime since the quotient $k[x,y,z]/J=k[x]$ is a domain.
As  you proved that $Y=Z(J)$ we have   $I(Y)=I(Z(J))=\sqrt J$ (by the Nullstellensatz) $=J$ , since we just saw that $J$ is prime.  So $I(Y)=J$, a prime.
But the condition that $Y$ be irreducible is exactly that $I(Y)$ be prime, so    $Y$ is indeed irreducible.
Our variety $Y$ is of dimension $1$ because it is the image of $\mathbb A^1_k$ under the non-constant morphism $t\mapsto (t,t^2,t^2)$.

Comment: I edited the original question with a question about your comment.

Comment: Nice answer, Georges. Alternatively, $Y$ is an open subset of the twisted cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$, so to show $J = (xy-z,x^2-y,xz-y^2) = (x^2-y,x^3-z) \subseteq k[x,y,z]$ is prime, it suffices to show $I := (xy-wz,x^2-yw,xz-y^2) \subseteq k[x,y,z,w]$ is prime, which can be done in generality e.g. by Grobner basis methods

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @zcn.